# How much geometry should I know for the AMC 12

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

I have been reading "Geometry Revisited" recently in prep for the amc 12, and just out of my own curiosity. It may seem very ambitious, but I'm hoping to at least get into AIME and possibly into USAMO. The last 3 chapters of "Geometry Revisited" cover more advanced transformations, inversive geometry, and projective geometry, and I wasn't sure if those were relevant to the AMC 12. "Introduction to Geometry" seems to be a lot more advanced, so I haven't read it yet, but I was wondering if there was any specific part or chapter of it I should read.

Sorry in advanced if I did anything wrong in my post, as this is my first time using Math Stack Exchange

Comment: "It may seem very ambitious, but I'm hoping to at least get into AIME and possibly into USAMO." You say that as if it's a bad thing to be ambitious about earning a spot in those competitions. I'm not familiar with USAMO or AIME, but I found [this link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/AIME_Problems_and_Solutions). You could also ask for help on this site about hard geometry questions and I'm sure more experienced people could help out.

Comment: [To the people who raised close votes on this post] There is one major question and it is where to practice for the USAMO and/or the AIME, specifically in the book Introduction to Geometry. So this is based on fact and not opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The AMC 12 includes topics through Pre-Calculus. I haven’t read that book, but I would recommend a book called Geometry by Moises E. Downs. I would recommend studying geometry, and trying to emphasize learning about applications of the Pythagorean theorem. Then you should try and study some trigonometry and definitely emphasize the basic trigonometric functions (sin, cos, tan). While you’re doing this, search up “AMC 12 Practice Problems” and a link to Art of Problem Solving will come up. Attempt to solve these past AMC problems and check your progress as you’re studying.

Good luck!